# Java: Gelf-Logstash -> Exceptions when "ssl:hostname"

Tags: java, ssl, log4j, logstash, sslhandshakeexception

I want to send my Error-Logs to my Graylog2 server with ssl. Unfortunately, I always get exceptions. I have installed my ssl/tls certificates in Java's `cacerts`. Also the certificate exists on my Graylog-Server.

## Exceptions:

```
log4j:ERROR General SSLEngine problem
java.io.IOException: Cannot send data to 192.168.10.74:12202
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfTCPSender.sendMessage(GelfTCPSender.java:126)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender.append(GelfLogAppender.java:92)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:322)
    at logging.J2Graylog.main(J2Graylog.java:19)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1336)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:519)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1197)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1169)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfTCPSSLSender.doHandshake(GelfTCPSSLSender.java:200)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfTCPSSLSender.connect(GelfTCPSSLSender.java:61)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfTCPSender.sendMessage(GelfTCPSender.java:103)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1703)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:841)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:839)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1273)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfTCPSSLSender.doHandshake(GelfTCPSSLSender.java:240)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:138)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1433)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 22 more
```

## log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.graylog2=biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender
log4j.appender.graylog2.Host=ssl:myGraylogHost
log4j.appender.graylog2.Port=myPort
log4j.appender.graylog2.originHost=localhost
log4j.appender.graylog2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.graylog2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d |%t|%c{1}| %-5p - %m%n
log4j.appender.graylog2.additionalFields={'environment': 'DEV', 'application': 'MyAPP'}
log4j.appender.graylog2.extractStackTrace=true
log4j.appender.graylog2.addExtendedInformation=true
log4j.appender.graylog2.Facility=gelf-java
```

Can someone tell me, why it throws so many exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Check following points

1. the code which is giving this exception is using which jre installation.go there and put certificate for your url.
2. you are using root certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jaydeep's post:

1. Verify the basic interoperability of your SSL setup. You can use a rather simple tool, see https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029.
2. `logstash-gelf` provides some configuration options regarding SSL, see [TCP Sender SSL documentation](http://logging.paluch.biz/tcp.html#SSL).
3. I noticed you're using IP addresses for the host name. Make sure your certificate contains the IP address as subject or [Subject Alternative Name (IP SANs)](https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm).